# Convert file path to URL

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib

```
path = 'C:\rough\3010999\CRESCENDO\Speaker\HATS_BA_crescendo__2018-05-31_18-33.html'
```

unable open the file through open and urllib.urlopen
Tried 
`urlparse.urljoin(`
`'file:', urllib.pathname2url(path))`
The fodler with `number` is encoding like `�0999`

help to open the file and read content..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6):

To convert the file path to a URI:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(r'C:\rough\3010999\CRESCENDO\Speaker\HATS_BA_crescendo__2018-05-31_18-33.html')
p.as_uri()
```

The result:

```
'file:///C:/rough/3010999/CRESCENDO/Speaker/HATS_BA_crescendo__2018-05-31_18-33.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `urllib.urlopen` to read urls.

Example below Should work

```
res = urllib.urlopen(urlparse.urljoin('file:', urllib.pathname2url(path)))
print res.read()  # Should print entire file content
```